# I can't use this nomenclature

Tags: css

I saw this nomenclature on a forum and was unable to use it.
[image]

I built my HTML this way:

```
<div class="div">
    <button class="div__button">Button</button>
</div<
```

And in the css, I did it in the same way as it is in the image, but it didn't work

What is missing? Is it because it's scss?

Comment: _Is it because it's scss?_ yep

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Please include code as text, not as pictures of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image you've posted uses [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/), it's an CSS preprocessor that allows you to use many features to generate CSS.

If you're using CodePen, go to your pen settings, on CSS tab, select SCSS preprocessor

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much